# Yii query builder like query

Tags: yii

I have the following query in yii query builder

**SQL Query**

```
select cartoon.cdate, cartoon.name 
from cartoon_tag, cartoon
where
     cartoon_tag.tags like '%$tag%'
     and cartoon_tag.c_id=cid
```

**Yii Query Builder**

```
$raw = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('cartoon.cdate,cartoon.name')
            ->from('cartoon,cartoon_tag')
            ->where('cartoon_tag.tags like :tag AND cartoon_tag.c_id=cid', array(':tag'=>$tag))
            ->queryAll();
```

Sql query provides correct result, but yii query builder not working correctly and provides exact match on `$tag` variable, not working like query. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like following

```
->where('cartoon_tag.tags like :tag AND cartoon_tag.c_id=cid', array(':tag'=>'%TOM%'))
```

Giving

```
 $raw = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('cartoon.cdate,cartoon.name')
->from('cartoon,cartoon_tag')
->where('cartoon_tag.tags like :tag AND cartoon_tag.c_id=cid', array(':tag'=>'%$tag%'))
->queryAll();
```

Comment: I try your answer, its not working.u put %TOM% and this is static. And I want to put variable.

Comment: Did you try the second part of my answer, first one was just an example

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

```
$tag=strtr($tag, array('%'=>'\%', '_'=>'\_'));
$raw = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('c.cdate,c.name')
->from('cartoon c')
->join('cartoon_tag ct','ct.c_id=c.cid')
->where(array('like', 'ct.tags', '%'.$tag.'%'))
->queryAll();
```

Now this is working.